# Use Mathematical Induction to prove that $^{2n}C_n < 2^{2n-2}$.

Tags: induction, combinations

Use Mathematical Induction to prove that $$^{2n}C_n < 2^{2n-2}$$ when $n\geq5$.

My attempt :

For $n=1$ , I got $LHS = 252 < RHS = 256$

Assumption  : $$^{2k}C_k < 2^{2k-2}$$

For $n=k+1$,

$$^{2(k+1)-2}C_{k+1} = 2\times ^{2k+1}C_{k}$$

$$= 2\times \{^{2k}C_{k}+^{2k}C_{k-1}\}$$

$$ < 2\times \{2^{2k-2}+^{2k}C_{k-1}\}$$

how can I proceed from this step?

Comment: I suggest using the notation $\binom{n}{k}$ rather than $~^nC_k$.  It is easier to read and is more common.

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1504755/prove-using-induction-that-2n-binom2nn-4n-for-n-geq-2?noredirect=1).